# Android self organiser with calendarView

Tags: android, calendar

Hi I'm trying to create app that will respond to clicked date on CalendarView, will get the date chosen and will display it in textview, here is my code:

```
public class MyOrganiser1Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView dateView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    CalendarView calendas = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);


    dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateView1);


    calendas.setOnDateChangeListener( new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        private GregorianCalendar calendar;

        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);

            SimpleDateFormat ss = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String currentdate= ss.format(calendar);
            dateView.setText(currentdate);
         }
      }); 
}
```

}

And my question is: Once i run this code; my app crash. Debug info:"can't find android.java for DataSetObservable.class".  However; i don't even know if this code above is correct.

Comment: And my question is: Once i run this code; my app crash. Debug info:"can't find android.java for DataSetObservable.class". However; i don't even know if this code above is correct.

Comment: Please show your code where you are using an instance of DataSetObservable

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using such a thing

Comment: Weird.  I can see an error in your code but nothing related to the error you posted re DataSetObservable.  I would clean your project.  The error in the code you have shown is that you declare dateView but you never assign it.

Comment: i guest like this: `dateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateView);`

Comment: OK, but where do you do this?  I can't see it in the code you've posted.

Comment: updated, but same DataSetObservable problem